# How do I see what version of certain libraries are being used by a snap package

Tags: firefox, snap, mesa

I'm trying to determine what version of MESA the latest firefox snap package is using.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: ... but are you asking about checking a version number for any particular package before installing the snap package of afterwards ?

Comment: No and no. I'm trying to determine what internal packages are inside the snap.  The snap package for whatever product like firefox or gimp has been built with certain libraries (MESA). So something like this if it were possible $ snap firefox apt list --installed.  So that I can see what packages are installed inside the snap.